# ¿Cómo saber si el usuario actual es administrador? C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms

Quiero saber si el usuario actual (el que ha iniciado actualmente sesión) es administrador o si es solo un usuario sin privilegios de administrador.

He estado probando el siguiente código:

```
MessageBox.Show((new WindowsPrincipal(WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent())
                   .IsInRole(WindowsBuiltInRole.Administrator)).ToString());
```

y este:

```
SecurityIdentifier sidadmin = new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.BuiltinAdministratorsSid, null);

MessageBox.Show((new WindowsPrincipal(WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent())
                   .IsInRole(sidadmin)).ToString());
```

Pero solo devuelve el tipo de privilegios con los que se está ejecutando la aplicación. Es decir si abro la aplicacion como "ejecutar como administrador" muestra true, si lo ejecuto "normal" muestra false AUNQUE el usuario actual sea cuenta de administrador.

Comment: Si lo que quieres es saber si el usuario forma parte del grupo de administradores, revisa esto: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30949544. Está en C++ pero puedes cargar las funciones que necesites con `DllImport` a C# si realmente quieres eso.

Comment: Realmente tengo poca experiencia y seguir esos pasos es un poco dificil. Pero me ayudó a comprender la información acerca del tema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He encontrado la forma, que es para algo simple que necesito. Es necesario tener .NET FRAMEWORK 4.5 o superior. Funciona muy bien lo he probado en maquinas fisicas y virtuales.

```
using System.Security.Principal;

using (var user = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent())
        {
            var principal = new WindowsPrincipal(user);
            // Check for token claim with well-known Administrators group SID
            const string LOCAL_ADMININSTRATORS_GROUP_SID = "S-1-5-32-544";
            if (principal.Claims.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Value == LOCAL_ADMININSTRATORS_GROUP_SID) != null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(true.ToString());
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show(false.ToString());
            }
```

Comment: También puedes reducir el if a `MessageBox.Show((principal.Claims.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Value == LOCAL_ADMININSTRATORS_GROUP_SID) != null).ToString());`. O si te parece un desastre, puedes guardar la condición en un bool y luego lo pasas a `MessageBox.Show()`.

Comment: Muchas gracias, funciona perfecto y me parece mejor asi. Pero todavia no termino de enterarme como lo hace sin el if.

Comment: Ya lo tengo, dejo la referencia por si a alguien le interesa. https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/boolean-logical-operators

Comment: Lo que sucede es que algunas expresiones resultan en un valor, como si de una función se tratase. Digamos `1 + 2` es una operación aritmética y te da un número (3). Así mismo, `1 == 1` es una comparación y resulta en `true`, un booleano. También existen otras operaciones. Entonces es más fácil decir `bool resultado = true; MessageBox.Show(resultado.ToString())` que `if (resultado) { MessageBox.Show("true"); }` o `if (resultado == true) { MessageBox.Show("true"); }`

Comment: Lo típico es ver que un principiante se maneje bien con operadores aritméticos y de comparación. A medida que va perfilando sus conocimientos y comprendiendo mejor lo que pasa, se dará cuenta que hay formas más sencillas de hacer las cosas y que incluso estaba añadiendo pasos innecesarios.

Comment: Yo sabia que los operadores evaluaban sus operandos, pero lo que no sabia era que generaban un valor. Antes de tu sugerencia lo probé  asi:        MessageBox.Show(principal.Claims.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Value == LOCAL_ADMININSTRATORS_GROUP_SID).ToString());  Pero no mostraba ningún resultado si el usuario no era administrador. Gracias por todo.